# Using a list within a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I am trying to use a list within a dict within a list. 
So what I am trying to do is use

```
add_counter = 0
put_lst = []
          while add_counter <= len(add_account_data_mutable)-1:
                put_lst.append(
                    {
                        'PutRequest': {
                            'Item': {
                                list_i_want_to_use[add_counter] #this has a dict type
                            }}
                    })
```

I keep getting this error on the line that starts with `'Item':{`

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict
```

Can someone please help me out.

Comment: You can use list in dictionary,Maybe `'Item': list_i_want_to_use[add_counter]`

Comment: Show a stack trace and fix your indentation

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
'PutRequest': {
    'Item': {
        list_i_want_to_use[add_counter]
    }
}
```

to:

```
'PutRequest': {
    'Item': list_i_want_to_use[add_counter]
}
```

The value `list_i_want_to_use[add_counter]` already has type `dict`, so you can just use it directly.  By wrapping it in curly brackets, you were constructing a `set` with the `dict` value as an element, which isn't allowed since `dict` values are unhashable.